# Fix jQuery scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll

Page **must be scrolled after clicking on link with id** (let it be #link).

Here is my code, which **doesnt work**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function () { 
        $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 2000 }, 'slow'); 
    });
});
```

But **this one works**, after the page loads it slowly scrolls to the bottom of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 6000 }, 'slow'); 
});
```

Height of the body is 6000px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, You're setting the scrollTop of the actual link element which has nothing within it to scroll. ( no overflow )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function () { 
        $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 2000 }, 'slow'); 
    });
});
```

Hers's a pretty good explanation of https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollTop

Comment: but if link is placed in the bottom (for example, from 4000px of the top corner) and I want to scroll it to the top, it scrolls from "top-to-the-point" (page throws to the top and then scrolls down), but needs to scroll from "bottom-to-the-top-point" (from existing point, without throwing). Pleeeease help me to fix that

Comment: if you want it to animate to the top from the bottom { scrollTop: 0 }

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your trying to animate 'this' which would be the link!

You should try $(window).animate instead! or maybe even document, sorry not sure!

Answer (score 1):

try $('html,body').animate to support all browsers